# Removing .php with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all my URLs to hide the `.php` extension. A general rule that adds `.php` to *all* URLs obviously won't do, so I want this rule to be conditional on the fact that

- There is no file nor directory that matches the URL
- After adding the `.php`, there *is* a match

I've arrived at these rewriting rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

The first two take care of checking whether the request can be satisfied without rewriting (so for images and other non-PHP content). With the third rule I'd like to check if adding `.php` would make the request valid (if not, we'll try something else further down the rewrite rules, or return 404).

The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` part never seems to match though. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The rewrite log is containing these entries:

```
(4) RewriteCond: input='/contact' pattern='!-f' => matched 
(4) RewriteCond: input='/contact' pattern='!-d' => matched 
(4) RewriteCond: input='/contact.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched
```

I find it strange that it's trying to match /contact, and not /var/www/mysite/htdocs/contact (At least that's what I'd expect when reading the docs on `REQUEST_FILENAME`). Apparently `REQUEST_FILENAME` is only what I expect when there is an actual match?

**EDIT2**

Thanks to [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181894/tomas) for the answer: use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` instead to manually compose the complete filename of the as yet unfound PHP file.

I've also thrown in an extra '/?' in the regexp to remove an optional / at the end of the URL, now all of /contact, /contact/ and /contact.php all refer to /contact.php:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1 !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**UPDATE**

After a lot of cursing I also found out that it depends on whether the RewriteRules are inside a <Directory> directive or .htaccess file on the one hand, or in your <VirtualHost> directive or just in the main body of an httpd.conf on the other hand. When inside a <Directory>/.htaccess, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` does contain the path so my initial solution should work there. Outside of <Directory>, you need to add the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure about using REQUEST_FILENAME. REQUEST_FILENAME should point to the full path of the matched file, but you are actually checking it's existence.

I would try something like:

```
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1         !-f
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php    -f
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$                      $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes from the RewriteLog it seems that `REQUEST_FILENAME` only gets populated with the 'full local filesystem path' the docs promise you if it actually *exists*. Your solution seems to solve this problem, I'll try it out!

Comment: Duh dumping code in comments really doesn't work... Anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: No. You could add the final answer to the question for clarity... Thanks.