# How to Mask Extension in URL

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to mask the URL extensions for pages on my website with PHP?
Example: http://home/subfolder instead of http://home.subfolder.php

Comment: http://home.subfolder.php? I didn't know .php was a TLD. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewrite all queries to not need the .php extension using a mod_rewrite RewriteRule](http://stackoverflow.com/q/183921/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the following in the .htaccess file in the root of your website

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache httpd's mod_rewrite can rewrite the URL transparently on the server side and let you use any URL you like.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, although it has nothing to do with PHP.

You'd have to create a file named `.htaccess` on the root of your webserver (if it does not yet exist). For instance, if you'd want to silently redirect users from /page/software/ to  index.php?page=software, you'd use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The initial part (`^page/([^/\.]+)/?$`) is a regular expression. If you're not sure how to use them, give us an example of what you're trying to do, and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, this is done with `mod_rewrite` if you're on an Apache-enabled server. Various questions have been asked similar to this:

Related:

1. [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-modrewrite)
2. [Removing .php with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672673/removing-php-with-modrewrite)