# href="blaah" instead of href="blaah.php" and href=".." instead of href="index.php"

Tags: php, html, apache, nginx, hyperlink

I have seen the use of `href="blaah"` instead of `href="blaah.php"` for the `href` attribute of the `a` tag. I have also seen `href=".."` in the stead of `href="index.php"`.

I have tested this on an NGINX server, but, when I host, I will probably end up hosting through Apache. So, is `href="blaah"` supported by Apache?

Comment: You are refering to a technique called URL rewriting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433545/how-to-make-extension-less-url-for-a-php-based-site

Comment: And most of the times, URLs such as `http://example.com/news/` can be (and should be) used instead of `http://example.com/news/index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RewriteEngine for this, just add this code to your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

This code adds .php to every file without a extension.

Comment: What about using `href=".."` instead of `href="index.php"`